# JavaScript - cannot call my object's methods

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a PhoneGap application for Android OS. I want to my application to be designed as most extendable as possible. Therefor I am writing all my modules as plgins, save them in one map and then I would like to use them in my HTML page. I wrote this code in MyJS.js file:

```
var map = {};

// Allow jQuery to cash the cordova.js
$.ajaxSetup({  cache: true});

$.getScript("cordova-2.6.0.js",function(){

    var AccelerometerSensor = {
            accelJSONObj:cordova.require("cordova/plugin/Acceleration"),
            accelPGAPSens:cordova.require("cordova/plugin/accelerometer"),


            color:'#FF8C00',
            sensorID:'Accelerometer',


            // Flag indicates whether this sensor type is supported by the device or not.
            availability:null,
            isAvailable:function() {
                accelPGAPSens.getCurrentAcceleration(
                        function(x){availability = true;}, 
                        function(){availability = false;});                  
            },

       }
})
.done(function(script, textStatus) {

    map["Accelerometer"] = this.AccelerometerSensor;
    alert('done');
 })
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
    alert('fail');
});
```

Now I want to call the isAvailable function, so I wrote this code:

```
map["Accelerometer"].isAvailable()
```

But I got a TypeError:

> "cannot call method 'isAvalable' of at undefined..."

What am I doing wrong? can anyone please show me what I have to do?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using :-

```
map["Accelerometer"] = this.AccelerometerSensor;
```

But "this" in done is different context i.e. global.

```
var map = {}, AccelerometerSensor;

// Allow jQuery to cash the cordova.js
$.ajaxSetup({  cache: true});

$.getScript("cordova-2.6.0.js",function(){

    AccelerometerSensor = {
            accelJSONObj:cordova.require("cordova/plugin/Acceleration"),
            accelPGAPSens:cordova.require("cordova/plugin/accelerometer"),


            color:'#FF8C00',
            sensorID:'Accelerometer',


            // Flag indicates whether this sensor type is supported by the device or not.
            availability:null,
            isAvailable:function() {
                accelPGAPSens.getCurrentAcceleration(
                        function(x){availability = true;}, 
                        function(){availability = false;});                  
            },

       }
})
.done(function(script, textStatus) {

    map["Accelerometer"] = AccelerometerSensor;
    alert('done');
 })
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {  
    alert('fail');
```

Comment: it's working now! thanks!. Just one another question now I am getting an error about the using of accelPGAPSens variable at the isAvailable() function that its not defined - can you please help me? thanks!

Comment: Try to use this.accelPGAPSens